# iOS Swift : Facebook Login & Parse Save

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parsing, authentication

I have a problem regarding login with Facebook.
If I set my account in Settings, for Facebook, when I try to use the account, I get this error : https://www.dropbox.com/s/8768a93mnvl0f0k/Screenshot%202015-06-16%2016.52.30.png?dl=0
Strangely, if I delete my account from Settings, I can log in.
I do not know what the problem is.
Thank you !

Comment: Any idea ? I read something about `FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent` , but I do not know exactly what to do. Thank you !

Comment: Please edit the question and add the following information: 1) How you initialize the Facebook SDK (add some code). 2) How you invoke Facebook Login (add some code here, too).

Comment: Sorry for the late update. I figured it out. I forgot to add a line in .plist. My mistake, sorry !